# Springboot in-memory table data not getting populated from data.sql

Tags: spring-boot, in-memory

I am loading my in-memory database table with data in it and it's never getting loaded from `data.sql`. I created my entity with the help of persistence.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String passportNumber;

}
```

And try to load data from data.sql as follows:

```
insert into student
values(10001,'Ranga', 'E1234567');

insert into student
values(10002,'Ravi', 'A1234568');
```

But my table never gets populated.

Comment: Did you follow [Spring's guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) on this?

Comment: yes I did but dint help

Comment: Do you have a link to the project? There isn't enough information here to help.